# @foreach data collection inside Ajax (Laravel)

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm completely new to ajax and trying to find a workaround how to complete these scenario since I can't find any that works for me.

I'm finding a way to populate the dropdown selection using foreach using AJAX. How I'm able to achieve it? I'm completely stuck here. Here's the AJAX script.

```
$('#kelompokumur_id').change(function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "{{url('fetch-anak')}}/"+id,
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        if(response.success){
          let dataArray = response.data
          $('#data_anak').empty()
          let res = dataArray.map((person, index) => {
          let list = `
              <tr class="btn-reveal-trigger">
                <td>${person.user.name}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="text-end">
                  <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" name="absensi[${person.id}]">
                    <option value="">Pilih Absensi</option>
                    <option value="1">PRESENT</option>
                    <option value="2">PERMIT</option>
                    <option value="3">SICK</option>
                    <option value="4">ALPHA</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
            `;
            $('#data_anak').append(list);
          });

        }
      }
  });
});
```

And here's the script that I tried to get the collection,

````
        return view('anak.absensi._inputabsen', compact('data_ku'));```
````

I tried this method, but it returns null since it's the closest I can get. Others show errors.

```
let list = `
              <tr class="btn-reveal-trigger">
                <td>${person.user.name}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td class="text-end">
                  <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" name="absensi[${person.id}]">`
@foreach($data_ku -> item)
                    <option value="{{$item -> id}}">{{$item -> attendance -> status}</option>
@endforeach
                  `</select>
                </td>
              </tr>
            `;
```

On controller:

```
public function create()
    {
        $data_ku = KelompokUmur::all();
        $kabsen = kodeabsensi::all();
        // dd($kabsen->toArray());
        return view('anak.absensi._inputabsen', compact('data_ku', 'kabsen'));
    }
```

when I dd($data_ku), this returns:

```
0 => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "kode_absen" => "AM"
    "nama_absen" => "Anak Malas"
    "keterangan" => "Anak Malas"
    "created_at" => "2023-01-13T17:27:49.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => "2023-01-13T17:27:49.000000Z"
  ]
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `@foreach($data_ku -> item)` That's not how `foreach` works. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#loops

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for the info. But still I can't find how to show it through the ajax

Answer (score 0):

While in the `*.blade.php` file you can do something like this. I did it outside of the script tags but you can also perform it inside:

```js
@php
    $data_ku_item_options = '';
    foreach ($data_ku as $item) {
        $data_ku_item_options .= "<option value=\"" . $item->id . "\">" . $item->attendance->status . "</option>";
    }
@endphp

<script>

$('#kelompokumur_id').change(function () {
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "{{url('fetch-anak')}}/" + id,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                let dataArray = response.data
                $('#data_anak').empty()
                let res = dataArray.map((person, index) => {
                    var options = "{{ $data_ku_item_options }}";
                    let list = `
                        <tr class="btn-reveal-trigger">
                        <td>${person.user.name}</td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td class="text-end">
                            <select class="form-select form-select-sm" aria-label=".form-select-sm example" name="absensi[${person.id}]">
                                ${options}
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    `;
                    $('#data_anak').append(list);
                });
            }
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

And `$data_ku = KelompokUmur::all();` change this line to:

```
$data_ku = KelompokUmur::with('attendance')->get();
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help but it's still returns null? Any idea?

Comment: before `return view('anak.absensi._inputabsen', compact('data_ku'))` in the method can you monitor the data with `dd($data_ku);`. Are you sure it's not returning empty data?

Comment: I did check it, but does return an array of data. No idea why

Comment: Could you please update your question to show me the inside of your controller method and a set of displayed data so I can assist you better?

Comment: Updated my questions with controller script

Comment: What exactly does `KelompokUmur::all()` return? Could you please add it to your question?

Comment: Updated again with the dd result

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you do my last addition and give feedback.

Comment: Still nothing. The data shows when I dd'ed it through controller through foreach, somehow the problems is on the @php itself.

Comment: These are issues other than your original question. We fixed fetching data along with your `attendance` method in your `KelompokUmur` model by changing the line in your method in Controller. But is your method inside the model working properly or is the data available? Because we did `$item->attendance->status` on the data navigating with foreach. That's why you can't see anything. Because there is no data. Replace `$item->attendance->status` with something else. The loop is working properly. You can ask a new question to fix your original problem. My answer answers this question.

Comment: I just found the answer, gonna post it after work tough

Answer (score -1):

Use this to get the collection of array in the JS

```
var absen = {!! json_encode($kabsen->toArray()) !!}
```

Then iterate it using $.each method in jQuery

```
$.each(absen, function(index, value) {
                      list += `<option value="${value.id}">${value.kode_absen}</option>`;
                    });
                    list +=
```

Comment: Your question does not have enough information to give this answer. This doesn't answer anything. Based on the data in your question, we understand that you are trying to display options relative to `$data_ku`. However, there are different variables here. When you don't explain them to us, we can't come up with any solutions.